# php Одновременная покупка

Tags: php

Есть 1 товар, два пользователя нажали оплатить этот товар, перенаправились на платежную систему, оплатил первый, через 20 сек второй, как предотвратить такое?
Получается второй уже находится на платежной систему и платежной системе передать сообщение, что товара уже нет нельзя, а заранее отмечать(перед перенаправлением на платежную систему), что товар уже куплен, не реально так как пользыватель может и не купить его, а другого пользователя упустить...

Comment: Не, придётся отмечать заранее, но эту отметку можно отменить позже, если например в течение часа товар так и не будет куплен

Comment: @andreymal за 1 час можно потерять других потенциальных покупателей

Comment: Перед направлением на платежную систему товар "лочится". Если запросившая покупку "сессия" не произвела оплату в течение некоторого времени, то товар "освобождается". Второй претендент получает приоритет перед любыми другими (в т.ч., естественно, новыми сессиями), Service-Worker выкидывает ему сообщение о возможности покупки.

Comment: @bsbak боюсь, с этим вряд ли можно что-то поделать. Все магазины, которые я юзал, делали именно так в течение этого часа писали что-то вроде «товар в резерве, может станет доступен если не купят»

Comment: @AlexanderZonov суть в том, что если товар разлочился, и купил его другой, а первый оплатил после того как разлочился, то первый начнет матерится, и говорить, а типо в айбокс бегал, че за нафиг

Comment: Я фигею, от систем оплаты, неужели нельзя реализовать запрос на актуальность за мгновение до перевода средств

Comment: Это сложный вопрос. Есть кнопка "купить", это еще на вашем сайте. Если ее кто-то нажал, то другим вы просто не позволяете перейти к оплате с сообщением типа "в данный момент этот товар пытается купить кто-то другой, если у него не получится, мы отправим вам пуш-уведомление и вы будете иметь приоритет перед всеми остальными в течение 5 минут".

Comment: @AlexanderZonov согласен, но первый уже был перенаправлен на оплату, через 5 минут он не оплатил, но все еще находится на странице оплаты, в этот момент купил второй по очереди, а первый оплатил тоже, но после второго, потому что уже был на стрнице оплаты..

Comment: @bsbak, а разве платежные системы не имеют время сессии? Когда я работал с ПС, были сессии, и если, допустим в течении 5 минут, ты не оплатил, то надо заново повторять процедуру. Это исключит возвращение к оплате 1 покупателя через какое-то время.

Comment: @erm в некоторых, нет возможности редактировать время сессии, в некоторых вообще нету.

Comment: А в вашей есть? Зачем редактировать? Допустим, если сессия 10 минут, то блокируйте товар на 10 минут как вам уже писали выше.

Comment: 20 век а все еще такая крывизна, 1 запрос на актуальность за мгновение до перевода, и все, а тут какие-то сессии, время ожидай, жди, час, два. пипец.

Answer (score 1):

Еще на стадии оформления заказа ставьте товар в резерв и уменьшайте его количество в основной таблице на величину резерва. Далее сделайте скрипт, который будет очищать зарезервированный, но неоплаченный товар (например, если клиент не оплатил товар в течение 3-х часов, то сбрасывается резерв, корзина и зарезервированное количество товара возвращается в основную таблицу).

Но на практике это крайне редкая ситуация. Куда чаще в интернет-торговле возникают проблемы не на стадии IT, а на стадии самой работы склада (когда по базе товар есть, а реально на складе его нет - недостача или тому подобная ситуация).

Answer (score 0):

Обычно это работает так:

- Вы выбираете в течении какого времени пользователь должен оплатить
  товар, после перехода в платежную систему. В среднем тут ставят 10
  минут, но всё зависит от типа вашего магазина.
- При создании заказа в Платежной Системе (ПС) вы указываете что ссылка
  должна жить в течении этого времени и на это же время блокируете
  товар для покупки. Пользователям можете сообщить что товар
  "Зарезервирован" или что уже куплен, на ваше усмотрение.
- Если получили подтверждение покупки, то проставляете что товар продан
  и больше не доступен для продажи. Ну и если не получили
  подтверждение, то возвращаете его обратно. Для этого обычно
  используют запуск скрипта в cron, который проверяет сколько уже
  времени заказ ожидает оплаты.

Если у вас количество товаров **может быть больше одного**, то этого всего не избежать.

НО! Если у вас товар **ВСЕГДА** в единичном экземпляре, то можно можно попробовать сделать так:

При создании заказа в ПС в качестве orderId проставляйте Id товара и тогда сама ПС будет отбивать второй платеж, потому что у них обычно стоит защита от двойной оплаты одного и того же заказа.

Я повторюсь, но так можно делать только если товар у вас **ВСЕГДА в единичном экземпляре**. Иначе точно что-нибудь сломается :)

Comment: Ой-ёй! Только сейчас заметил, что этому посту несколько лет. ) Простите извините! ))